# Como reiniciar botones con values en javascript

Tags: javascript, html, botón, dom

Estoy haciendo tres botones en el cuales aparecen X en cada boton, una vez que aparece la X al apretar el ultimo boton aparece un mensaje diciendo: "Has apretado todos los botones ahora nos reiniciaremos los tres"
Una vez que yo aprieto esos botones he dejado unas instrucciones para vaciar esos botones, el problema es que no se como hacer para que se me reinicie los botones y el 'mensaje que doy por innerHTML' y que vuelva a comenzar de nuevo.
Solamente he podido llegar a que se reinicie la interfaz por así decirlo pero no me deja clickear nuevamente y tampoco se me reinicia el mensaje que doy por pantalla y no entiendo por que.

```js
const btnUno = document.getElementById('btnX1')
const btnDos = document.getElementById('btnX2')
const btnTres = document.getElementById('btnX3')
const texto = document.querySelector('.textoplano')

a=0;

function miFuncion(boton){

    if (a == 0){
        a = a+1;
        boton.value = "X"
        boton.disabled = true;
        
    } else {
    a = a-1
    boton.value = "X"
    boton.disabled = true;
    }
    
        apretarBotones();
}


function apretarBotones () {

 if (btnUno.value == 'X' && btnDos.value == 'X' && btnTres.value =='X'){
        texto.innerHTML = "Has apretado los tres botones"
        btnUno.value = ""
        btnDos.value = ""
        btnTres.value = "" 
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaTateti">

    <tr><td><input type="button" value=" " name="button" id="btnX1" onclick="miFuncion(this)"></button></td>
        <td><input type="button" value=" "  name="boton1" id="btnX2" onclick="miFuncion(this)"></button></td>
        <td><input type="button" value =" "  name ="boton1" id="btnX3" onclick="miFuncion(this)"></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<span class="textoplano" ></span>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema es que no solo cambiaste el valor de los botones por una X, también los deshabilitaste `boton.disabled = true;`, pero solo restableces los valores y no cambias esa propiedad.

Te sugiero usar `setTimeout()` para esperar un tiempo (2 segundos en el ejemplo), para que el usuario pueda leer el mensaje antes de reiniciar.

```js
const btnUno = document.getElementById('btnX1')
const btnDos = document.getElementById('btnX2')
const btnTres = document.getElementById('btnX3')
const texto = document.querySelector('.textoplano')

a=0;

function miFuncion(boton){

    if (a == 0){
        a = a+1;
        boton.value = "X"
        boton.disabled = true;
        
    } else {
    a = a-1
    boton.value = "X"
    boton.disabled = true;
    }
    
        apretarBotones();
}


function apretarBotones () {
    if (btnUno.value == 'X' && btnDos.value == 'X' && btnTres.value =='X'){
        texto.innerHTML = "Has apretado los tres botones";
        // Volver a habilitar botones y quitar el mensaje
        setTimeout(() => {
            // Restablecer valores
            btnUno.value = ""
            btnDos.value = ""
            btnTres.value = ""
            // Habilitar botones
            btnUno.disabled = false;
            btnDos.disabled = false;
            btnTres.disabled = false;
            // Eliminar mensaje
            texto.innerHTML = '';
        }, 2000);
    }
}
```

```html
<table id="tablaTateti">

    <tr><td><input type="button" value=" " name="button" id="btnX1" onclick="miFuncion(this)"></button></td>
        <td><input type="button" value=" "  name="boton1" id="btnX2" onclick="miFuncion(this)"></button></td>
        <td><input type="button" value =" "  name ="boton1" id="btnX3" onclick="miFuncion(this)"></button></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<br>
<span class="textoplano" ></span>
```